# Installing Ubuntu 14.04 over 12.04

Tags: 14.04, system-installation

Does the installation of Ubuntu 14.04 recognise that there is already a version of Ubuntu installed on the computer?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it does.

When you boot the 14.04 installation media, it will give you a number of options including :

- Upgrade from 12.04 to 14.04
- Install 14.04 alongside 12.04
- Erase 12.04 and do a fresh install of 14.04
- Something else

Comment: I tried to upgrade recently on a dual boot (Windows 7 & 12.04) to 14.04.1 via Live USB and the choices were * Install Ubuntu alongside the other OSs, * Erase disk and install Ubuntu (removes all files in all OSs) and * Something else. But there was no upgrade option (which is what I wanted). I ended up erasing the 12.04 partition and installing from scratch.

Comment: @Fernhill Linux Project no way! really? also if now I have 64bit and want to upgrade to a 32bit?

Comment: I have dual boot (win+ubuntu), if I decide to "Upgrade from 12.04 to 14.04" does the grub remain?

Comment: You cannot upgrade to a different architecture (64 bit to 32 bit), this will require a fresh install. You can upgrade 64 to 64 or 32 to 32 no problems. Grub will remain and be updated during the installation process.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it does.

Type this in terminal

```
sudo update-manager -d
```

Hit the return/enter key and, if prompted, enter your user password.

The Update Manager application will open after a few seconds with a prompt to upgrade.

Click this button to begin the process.